# What does Mixpanel's $signup event do?

Tags: mixpanel

I've heard that the '$signup' event in Mixpanel is somehow special. What exactly does it do?

All I've been able to find are very vague statements like "there will be a slight improvement in performance for your report" and "$signup is particularly useful for retention analysis."

Comment: The only mention we've tracked down is in the import documentation: https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/importing-events-older-than-31-days - we're going to just start tracking it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to send the "$signup" event since ~2012. The special "$signup" event was hardcoded as the first event in Retention reports, but the query API and web app allow users to specify any event.